# Manipulate data on serializer before creating model instance in DangoRestFramework

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-3.6

I have three related models as such

> Order model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    Name  =  models.CharField(max_length=250)
    orderType = models.ForeignKey(OrderType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.Name)enter code here
```

> OrderPricing Model

```
class OrderPricing(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    TotalPrice =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    #related field
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.TotalPrice
```

> OrderType Model

```
class OrderType(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    Premium =  models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
```

1. Let's ignore the order in which the models appear above.
2. I have three SerializerModels for each model.
3. I can crud each model on the BrowsableAPI

Q1:

From the browsableAPI I can create an Order.

I haven't gotten to the 'Writable Nested Serializer' yet and I believe Django has that figured out in their docs through the drf-writable-nested class.

I have two orderTypes

1 = {'Not Premium':'False'}   #not Premium

2 = {'Premium':'True'}    #Premium

> Assume I have a variable **order_price** = 5 #£5
>
> How can I

1. Create an order,
2. If order is premium, then set order_price to 10 #order_price * 2
3. If order is NOT premium, then set order_price to 5
4. Create an instance of OrderPricing, that's related to the order. Also, pass the **order_price** variable to the property **TotalPrice** when creating the instance

from what I have seen and tried, I can override the Create() on the serializer as such

```
class OrderSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    """OrderSerializer"""
    # orderPricing = OrderPricingSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('__all__')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        #create instance of order
        #determine of order is premium
        typeid = uuid.UUID(validated_data.pop('orderType'))#get FK value
        isPremium = OrderType.objects.get(id = str(typeid.id))#determine if **Premium** is True/False

        # set/calculate the price of the order
        #create a related instance of OrderPricing
```

> Q2
>   I am aware of GenericViews and the CreateModelMixin, what I don't know is, which is better, overriding the .create() at the serializer or overriding the CreateModelMixin method at the GenericView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, where to put business logic is always question hard to answer. 
You have multiple places where it can be - view, serializer, model or some other separate module/service.

All have pros and cons- you can find many articles on this topic.

But in your case, I would probably go with `perform_create` of your view and I would create a method in the serializer which would update the price. If I needed to use the code to update price, I'd move to separate shared module and call it from there.

So let's say you use `CreateModelMixin` or better `ListCreateAPIView`

```
class YourView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer = OrderSerializer
    queryset = your_queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
         serializer.update_price()
         serializer.save()
```

`perform_create` is called after data is validated, so you can access the validated data.

`update_price` is your code where you update the price.

You can argue to move this logic to serializer's create or save method but they do many other things, so unless you need to override these methods for other reasons - you can take advantage of the `perform_create` method.